# Reading output from a process

Tags: java, bufferedreader, runtime.exec

I am trying to use BufferedReader to read the output of a process. When I try

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nslookup 10.123.30.130"); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
    System.out.println(line); 
    line=reader.readLine(); 
}
```

the output is

```
Server:  <edited server details>
Address:  <edited address details>
```

whereas the actual output of the process in the console is:

```
Server:  <details edited>
Address:  <details edited>

Name:    <details edited>
Address:  <details edited>
```

(Note: I have edited the actual output for security reasons)

My observation is that after reading the first 2 lines, null is returned and hence the stream ends. Is there any way I could get the full four lines?

---

**Update**:
The third empty line is being interpreted as a null. But if I try the same program for  `Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");` I get the output exactly as in the console even though there are new lines.

Comment: I thought you want to read output! **p.getOutputStream**

Comment: perhaps the empty line in the middle is interpreted as null?

Comment: 1) Go through the article linked from the [exec tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & implement all suggestions.  That might lead to a solution to the immediate problem, but also.. 2) Use a `ProcessBuilder` that makes it easier to implement point (1) and.. 3) Provide arguments as an array.  E.G. `"nslookup","10.123.30.130"`.

Comment: Don't forget to read also an Error Stream: `p.getErrorStream();`

Answer (score 0):

Read error buffer as well.

```
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

String errorLine;
while( (errorLine = stdError.readLine()) != null ){
  System.out.println(errorLine);
}
```

You'll see that there is an error and *nslookup* can't resolve the domain for your IP address. Use host name instead of the IP address.